# RxAndroid: Possible to use zip function on an array of api requests with interval or delay?

Tags: android, api, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am playing around with RxAndroid. I have a List of Observables all of which are api requests (using Retrofit). I want to fire one of them every x seconds or milliseconds but then zip the responses together.  I seems that once I subscribe to Observable.zip(requests, someFunction) all of them are fired off at once. Any tips?

Thanks!

EDIT: looks like adding delaySubscription to each request maybe the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for either [`delay()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) or `delaySubscription()`.

`delay()` will delay the *result* of the Observable being published to the subscriber.
`delaySubscription()` will delay *subscription* to the Observable.

`Observable.zip(someObservable.delaySubscription(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    someOtherObservable.delaySubscription(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    someThirdObservable.delaySubscription(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    new Func3<Object, Object, Object, Void>() {
        ...
    }).subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's posible to achieve a *periodical sending effect* by using the `interval()` operator.

Let's see a simple example. Imagine you have an array, `numbers`, whose values have to emitted each x time. You could create an `Observable` that emits them:

```
Observable<Integer> values = Observable.from(numbers);
```

And now, another `Observable` that emits each (for instance) 30 milliseconds:

```
Observable<Long> interval = Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

So, through the `zip()` operator you could combine both to achieve the periodical emission of the values in your `number` array:

```
Observable.zip(values, interval, (arrayElement, aLong) -> arrayElement)
    .subscribe(arrayElement -> doSomething(arrayElement));
```

I used it to get an animation effect for a progress indicator. I wrote a complete example project you can check in [github](https://github.com/danilao/android-mvp-rx-animation-example).